# RegEx for matching everything except a repeating char at start and end

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a string pattern and the examples are below.

```
AA4grgrsragrga4334grAA

AAA4323425AAA

AAAAAA%%%AAAAAA
```

Leading 'A's and trailing As always appear in pair.

I have tried:

```
A+.+A+
```

No idea how to pair up the leading As and trailing As in REGEX.

Comment: Which definition of regex are you using? The answer may depend on this.

Comment: Are those `*`s at the beginning and end actually in the string, or were they an attempt at formatting the code for the question?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yep, they were for italic. Corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you als want to match paired A's at the start and the end for strings like AA, or AAAAAA  but also AAteAstAA you could use an alternation:

```
^(A+)(?:[^A].*[^A]|[^A])?\1$
```

About the pattern

- `^` Start of string
- `(A+)` Capture in the first group matching 1+ A's
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^A].*[^A]` Match not A, 0+ times any char except newline, then again not A
  - `|` Or
  - `[^A]` Match not A
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `\1` Back reference to group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0sXpak/1)

If AAA can also match you can use

```
^(A+)(?:[^A].*[^A]|.)?\1$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0sXpak/2)

Answer (score 2):

Capture the initial As in a group, then repeatedly match any characters followed by a non-`A`, then backreference the first group again, followed by the end of the string:

```
^(A+).*[^A]\1$
```

https://regex101.com/r/81ge2k/2

If `A` will only appear at the beginning and end of the string, you can use a negative character set instead:

```
^(A+)[^A]*\1$
```

Make sure to use start-of-string and end-of-string anchors if the input string is supposed to span the whole line, otherwise the pattern can match mismatched `A`s.

Comment: Are you sure this will not match `AAzzAAA`?

Comment: Good point, thanks, need to make sure the last character before the trailing As is not an A

Answer (score 0):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/Y9pGHw/1) has a simple capturing group in between `A+`, that swipe every non-A chars in between from left to right:

```
A+([^A]*)A+
```

[image]

---

If you wish to capture `A+`, you can simply wrap them with two capturing groups `()`, similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/uPvWU1/1):

```
(A+)([^A]*)(A+)
```

[image]

---

If you do not wish to match the `A` char, then you could simply remove them from [the expression](https://regex101.com/r/dS87uI/1):

```
[^A]*
```

However this would not match if there would A in between, and needs to be modified.

---

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This graph visualizes the expression, and if you want, you can test other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /(A+)([^A]*)(A+)/gm;
const str = `AA4grgrsragrga4334grAA
AAA4323425AAA
AAAAAA%%%AAAAAA`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Basic Performance Test for (A+)([^A]*)(A+)

This JavaScript snippet returns runtime of a 1-million times `for` loop for performance.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'AAAAAAAAAanyThingElse4grgrsragrga4334grAAAA';
 const regex = /(A+)([^A]*)(A+)/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "\nGroup #1: $1\nGroup #2: $2\nGroup #3: $3\n");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

#### Basic Performance Test for A+([^A]*)A+

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'AAAAAAAAAanyThingElse4grgrsragrga4334grAAAA';
 const regex = /A+([^A]*)A+/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "Group #1: $1");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: Your regex matches `AA***A` but it shouldn't. "Leading 'A's and trailing As always appear in pair."